# Managing files in cloud (Dropbox, GDrive) using javascript

Tags: javascript, cloud, dropbox

I want to make browser application, that will manage user's files in file cloud's like Dropbox or Google Drive. It is possible to do it only in javascript without PHP? How can I access to user's files?

Comment: I'm not sure extractly

Answer (score 1):

Dive into https://www.dropbox.com/developers/chooser - here valuable samples on JavaScript.

Comment: but it is only loading files from cloud. I want to create new files, read and edit it.